# How to work around Firefox's miscalculation of widths

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

Under some situations, Firefox grossly miscalculates the widths of some DOM elements, which in turn causes layouts to break.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfkL9/) gives an example of the problem.  The numbers displayed below the table are the widths (in pixels) of the `div` that is shaded dark-gray, and of its parent (as reported by jQuery).  Compare the results produced by the latest versions of Firefox (or IE 11) and Chrome (or Safari).  Chrome always reports 250 for both widths (as expected), but Firefox always reports a larger number (though the exact number may depend on the OS and/or version of FF and/or phase of the moon).  As a result, there's not enough room to render the `svg` elements in the next `td` at 3/row.

(More bewildering still: the numbers displayed below the table will vary according to the *number* of `svg` elements included in the second `td` element.)

This erratic/unpredictable behavior makes it practically impossible to design a layout.

How can I ensure that FF will compute such widths correctly, or alternatively, how can I work around this bug?

EDIT: updated jsFiddle (including the link to it).

---

Now, to keep the gods of SO happy:

```
body > div,table,table *{outline:1px solid red;}

html,body{height:100%;}
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}
table{
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

body{
  font-family:courier;
  font-size:13px;
  background-color:palegoldenrod;
}

body > div{
  width:312px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:40px 0 0;
  background-color:white;
  min-height:100%;
}

label{
  display:block;
  padding:0 1ex;
}

.button-container{
  color:white;
  background-color:#555;
}
.button-container > div{
  display:inline-block;
}

.button-container > div:first-child{
  font-weight:bold;
}

.ul-container > div{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
          border-radius:4px;
}
ul{list-style:none;}
li{
  width: 72px;
  float:left;
  margin: 0px 5px 1px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
br{
  clear:left;
}

body > div > div:last-child{margin:40px;}
```

```
<body>

  <div>

    <table><tbody><tr>
      <td>

         <div class="button-container">
           <div>xxxx xxxxx</div>
           <div>
             <label> <input type="radio"> xxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxxx </label>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="ul-container" style="width: 250px;">
           <div style="width: 248px;">
             <ul style="width: 246px;">
               <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li><li>G</li><li>H</li><li>I</li>
             </ul>
             <br>
           </div>
         </div>

      </td>

      <td>
        <div>
          <svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg><svg width="20" height="20"></svg>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr></tbody></table>

    <div></div>

  </div>
```

```
(function ($) {
  var $msg = $('body > div > div:last-child');
  function showw (sel) {
    var w = $(sel).width();
    $('<span>', {text: '' + w})
        .css('margin-left', 5)
        .appendTo($msg);
    console.log(w);
  }
  showw('.button-container');
  showw('table td:first-child');
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `inline-block` rule for `.button-container > div`, it forces the two divs to sit on separate lines, allowing the table to take on a consistent width.

What is happening there is the browser is trying to put the elements on the same line. A cell in a table with no explicit width or overflow instructions will grow wider to accommodate the content lines inside it. Because the two elements are inline, they are considered a single line. The text wraps as you would expect (the browser does a good job protecting the integrity of your content), but this is arbitrary as far as the width calculation goes; it affects the calculated width of the line that the elements form, and therefore pushes the table cell open wider. The browser is trying to take what you gave it and make sense of it while it also tries to preserve the integrity and legibility of your data, because it is a table and that's what tables do.

This is another good example of why tables are not the right tool for layout. They are designed to accommodate and present data, so they do a good job flowing and sizing around text. Different user agents have different strategies when it comes to how this is accomplished -- that is all within the specification. When you abuse the element, you wind up having to contend with design properties that do not suit your use case.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy7dA/

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion: one man's bug is another man's feature.  The way that Chrome and Safari handle the matter seems to me obviously correct, but reasonable minds may disagree on this.  BTW, I doctored the example to make Chrome and Firefox both require two lines to display the contents of `.button-container`, but the original situation was such that, on Windows, only one line was required, but on OS X two lines were required.  The one-line arrangement, when possible, was preferred, and that was the reason for the `inline-block`.  Without it, two lines will be enforced, whether...

Comment: @kjo The fact remains that tables are not a layout element, so when you expect the table engine to perform as a layout engine, it is bound to fall short. That Chrome and Safari calculate the line width differently is more of a quirk of implementation rather than by design.

Comment: My use of tables for layout is really just an act of desperation.  :/  Programming with CSS and the W3C layout model is ***by far*** the most harrowing programming experience in my 30 years in the business, incomparably worse than the usual "monsters", like LISP, regexps, Haskell, Prolog, etc.  I find the behavior of table-based layouts *usually* more predictable (by me) than that of table-less layouts.  This was a rare instance when this strategy backfired.  BTW, I found the solution to my problem, and it is embarrassingly simple: just set the width of `#left-panel` to 250px.

Comment: That is also a valid route :)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "miscalculating the width" at all.

Your problem is simply that your label and input are different widths in both browsers. The extra width is then pushing the button-container and td out further.

Try to get your input/label combo consistent between the browsers (you probably need explicit margins on the input) and your problem is solved.

Comment: ***look at the text:*** it's right edge is nowhere near the right edge of the containing element; the width of the text is 205px, far below the width that FF assigns to the containing element.

Comment: Yes but delete the label/input and see what happens. You have a bunch of weird global selectors so there's a good chance you're getting a large right margin after the label.

Comment: please post ***guesses*** as comments rather than answers.